# Blogger button link change after clicking it

Tags: html, button, uibutton, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

In blogger, if the user click the button, it redirect to desired link. If the user click the same button for second time, I want to make the button to be redirected to another link. So how can I change the blogger button link to another link after clicking it?

I have searched and tried for two months. But I have no idea yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code for your question. here is some code idea that you can implement on your side.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // Secound URL Set For False
    var get_url = false;

    $('button').click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        // Define URL
        var btn_url = $(this).data('url');
        var btn_url2 = $(this).data('url2');

        // First Url Execute
        if (get_url != true) {
            window.open(btn_url, '_blank');
            // First URL Clicked
            get_url = true;
        } 
        // Secound Url Execute
        else {
            window.open(btn_url2, '_blank');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-url="https://stackoverflow.com/" data-url2="google.com">Blogger BTN</button>
```